# simpleXMLElement remove by yourself encoding

Tags: php, xml

I need to create an XML in PHP.

My code start with:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><iv:Fornitura xmlns:cm="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:common" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:tm="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:telent:v1" xmlns:iv="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:ivp"></iv:Fornitura>', LIBXML_NOERROR, false, 'iv', true);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$dom_xml = dom_import_simplexml($doc);
$dom_xml = $dom->importNode($dom_xml, true);
$dom_xml = $dom->appendChild($dom_xml);

$file_XML = $dom->saveXML();    // SAVE TO STRING
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <iv:Fornitura xmlns:cm="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:common" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"  xmlns:iv="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:ivp">
  </iv:Fornitura>
```

But I always get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <iv:Fornitura xmlns:cm="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:common" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"  xmlns:iv="urn:www.agenziaentrate.gov.it:specificheTecniche:sco:ivp">
  </iv:Fornitura>
```

It seem encoding `encoding="UTF-8"` disappear. Using also addAttribute doesn't work.

Comment: `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');` open a manual sometimes.

Comment: It is not SimplyXML losing the encoding here (a simple $doc->asXML() would have shown you that), but the combination with DOMDocument.

Comment: @u_mulder you are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than disappearing, I'd say it never gets added in the first place:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
```

As per [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php):

```
public DOMDocument::__construct ([ string $version [, string $encoding ]] )`
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kqdrs)